# Weibull Distribution question

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variables

Not sure how to approach this one, some help would be appreciated.

> It has been observed that 5% of the students who take a certain exam will finish in less than 20 minutes and 95% will finish in less than 90 minutes. Assume the time to finish is a Weibull random variable.
>   a) Find alpha, beta, mu, and sigma
>   b) Find the probability that a student will finish the exam
>   in less than 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the formula for the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of the Weibull distribution (I'm assuming you're calling the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$)?  The first sentence tells you
two values of that CDF.  That gives you two equations, from which you are to determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$.